# After migrating a VS 2005 project to VS 2010, I have web references causing troubles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, migration, webservice-client

I have a winform project build on VS 2005 and framework 2. Recently, we moved to VS 2010, but keeping the framework v2 as target.

Everything runs fine except my web references.

When I update the web references, a new file "Reference1.cs" is created, under the reference.map file. This is causing troubles as original "Reference.cs" is still here and all classes are duplicated.

Here is the project structure :

- My winform project

  - Web references

    - MyWebServiceReference

      - WebService.disco
      - webservice.wsdl
      - Reference.map

        - mycomplextype.datasource
        - Reference.cs
        - Reference1.cs

On the reference.map file, I have a custom tool defined : MSDiscoCodeGenerator. This custom tool seems to throw a warning :

> Warning    1   A custom tool 'MSDiscoCodeGenerator' is associated with file 'Web References\MyWebService\Reference.map', but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.  You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.

If I run the custom tool, the file reference1.cs is generated...

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would try deleting the web reference and re-adding instead of updating.

Comment: @Matt F: you can answer the question to get the reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try deleting the web reference and re-adding instead of updating.